# How to use tensorflow's Dataset API Iterator as an input of a (recurrent) neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

When using the tensorflow's Dataset API Iterator, my goal is to define an RNN that operates on the iterator's `get_next()` tensors as its input (see `(1)` in the code).

However, simply defining the `dynamic_rnn` with `get_next()` as its input results in an error: `ValueError: Initializer for variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel/ is from inside a control-flow construct, such as a loop or conditional. When creating a variable inside a loop or conditional, use a lambda as the initializer.`

Now I know that one workaround is to simply create a placeholder for `next_batch` and then `eval()` the tensor (because you can't pass the tensor itself) and pass it using `feed_dict` (see `X` and `(2)` in the code).
However, if I understand it correctly, this is not an efficient solution as we first evaluate and then reinitialize the tensor.

Is there any way to either:

1. Define the `dynamic_rnn` directly on top of the output of the Iterator;

or:

2. Somehow directly pass the existing `get_next()` tensor to the placeholder that is the input of `dynamic_rnn`?

Full working example; the `(1)` version is what I would like to work but it doesn't, while `(2)` is the workaround that does work.

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import BasicLSTMCell
from tensorflow.python.data import Iterator

data = [ [[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]], [[1], [2], [3]] ]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
dataset = dataset.batch(2)
iterator = Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types,
                                   dataset.output_shapes)
next_batch = iterator.get_next()
iterator_init = iterator.make_initializer(dataset)

# (2):
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3, 1))

cell = BasicLSTMCell(num_units=8)

# (1):
# outputs, states = lstm_outputs, lstm_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, next_batch, dtype=tf.float32)

# (2):
outputs, states = lstm_outputs, lstm_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(iterator_init)

    # (1):
    # o, s = sess.run([outputs, states])
    # o, s = sess.run([outputs, states])

    # (2):
    o, s = sess.run([outputs, states], feed_dict={X: next_batch.eval()})
    o, s = sess.run([outputs, states], feed_dict={X: next_batch.eval()})
```

(Using tensorflow 1.4.0, Python 3.6.)

Thank you very much :)

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but your code helped me to figure out that I should use eval() when feeding elements from a "Dataset" to session.run. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the mysterious error is likely a bug in tensorflow, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14729. More specifically, the error really comes from feeding a wrong data type (in my example above, the `data` array contains `int32` values but it should contain floats).

Instead of getting the `ValueError: Initializer for variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel/ is from inside a control-flow construct` error,
tensorflow should return:
`TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [int32, float32] that don't all match.` (see [1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14729)).

To fix this problem, simply change
`data = [ [[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]], [[1], [2], [3]] ]`
to
`data = np.array([[ [1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]], [[1], [2], [3]] ], dtype=np.float32)`

and then the following code shall work properly:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import BasicLSTMCell
from tensorflow.python.data import Iterator

data = np.array([[ [1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]], [[1], [2], [3]] ], dtype=np.float32)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
dataset = dataset.batch(2)
iterator = Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types,
                                   dataset.output_shapes)
next_batch = iterator.get_next()
iterator_init = iterator.make_initializer(dataset)

# (2):
# X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3, 1))

cell = BasicLSTMCell(num_units=8)

# (1):
outputs, states = lstm_outputs, lstm_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, next_batch, dtype=tf.float32)

# (2):
# outputs, states = lstm_outputs, lstm_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(iterator_init)

    # (1):
    o, s = sess.run([outputs, states])
    o, s = sess.run([outputs, states])

    # (2):
    # o, s = sess.run([outputs, states], feed_dict={X: next_batch.eval()})
    # o, s = sess.run([outputs, states], feed_dict={X: next_batch.eval()})
```

Comment: Why is the shape of outputs `(1,3,8)` though? There are 3 observations.

Comment: See what [dynamic_rnn returns](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn).

The `1` is the batch size (because we define it on only one batch, `next_batch`), `3` is the number of timestamps within one batch, `8` is the number of RNN units.

Comment: But in your example you batch 2 observations in your instance.

Comment: Ah, you're right, didn't notice. In that case, the shape would be `(2,3,8)`. Where did you get `(1,3,8)`?

Comment: Minimal working example you gave spits out the shape of `o` as `(1,3,8)`.

Comment: You are [technically correct](https://www.reddit.com/r/technicallythetruth), although it also spits out the shape of `(2,3,8)`.

Simply put, since the dataset has three elements, the first iteration outputs shape `(2,3,8)` and the second iteration outputs shape `(1,3,8)`.

The code is able to handle any batch size. Typically, you would have a cycle iterating over the dataset. Here, for the sake of clarity, the RNN is simply run twice, first time on the first two dataset elements and then on the last (third) element.

Comment: oh! shoot! Silly me! Yes, the last `o` is overwriting the first `o`. Shoot! I got it now! thank you!