# Keras, tensorflow: Initializer for variable... is from inside a control-flow construct, a loop or conditional

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am training a mask r-cnn model refer to this rep on github:
https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN

I meet a problem which seems to be an issue of using Keras, so I come here.

The code calculates masks from region of interest(rois) and feature map:

```
mrcnn_mask = build_fpn_mask_graph(rois, mrcnn_feature_maps,
    config.IMAGE_SHAPE,
    config.MASK_POOL_SIZE,
    config.NUM_CLASSES)
```

However, sometimes rois maybe all zeros, in which case I want to return all zeros directly. So, I use tf.cond like this:

```
def ff_true():
    mrcnn_mask = build_fpn_mask_graph(rois, mrcnn_feature_maps,
       config.IMAGE_SHAPE,
       config.MASK_POOL_SIZE,
       config.NUM_CLASSES)

def ff_false():
    return tf.zeros_like(target_mask)

mrcnn_mask = KL.Lambda(lambda x: tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.reduce_mean(x), 0), 
    ff_true, ff_true)) (rois)
```

This raises an error:

> ValueError: Initializer for variable lambda_5/cond/mrcnn_mask_conv1/kernel/ is from inside a control-flow construct, such as a loop or conditional. When creating a variable inside a loop or conditional, use a lambda as the initializer.

I google it but no useful info got.
This seems to be an issue of falsely using keras/tensorflow.
Any clue will be welcomed!

BTW, if I use this code, it will be no error(but I don't want to calculate a in advance):

```
a = build_fpn_mask_graph(rois, mrcnn_feature_maps,
    config.IMAGE_SHAPE,
    config.MASK_POOL_SIZE,
    config.NUM_CLASSES)   
def ff_true():
    return a
def ff_false():
    return tf.zeros_like(target_mask)

mrcnn_mask = KL.Lambda(lambda x: tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.reduce_mean(x), 0), 
    ff_true, ff_true)) (rois)
```

Comment: Sometimes this error can arise due to a datatype mismatch (e.g. trying to concatenate tensors of type tf.float32 and tf.int32). This is discussed in more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393356/how-to-use-tensorflows-dataset-api-iterator-as-an-input-of-a-recurrent-neural/47409487 and here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14729. Unfortunately, I don't think this is actually the case with your code, since you have an actual lambda.  But even if it isn't, the links might be of use to others who find this question while googling that error.

Comment: Yes, it's not a problem of datatype.
This is just a problem of Keras. Keras uses tensors to initialize variables, which is not legal inside conditional. Refer to: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/170
I haven't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error is basically what the message says. You cannot have a variable initializer inside a conditional. A crude analogy to normal programming languages is:

```
if my_condition:
    a = 1
print a    # can't do this. a might be uninitialized.
```

Here is a simple example to illustrate this issue and the fix suggested in the error message:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def cond(i, _):
  return i < 10

def body(i, _):
  zero = tf.zeros([], dtype=tf.int32)
  v = tf.Variable(initial_value=zero)
  return (i + 1, v.read_value())

def body_ok(i, _):
  zero = lambda: tf.zeros([], dtype=tf.int32)
  v = tf.Variable(initial_value=zero, dtype=tf.int32)
  return (i + 1, v.read_value())

tf.while_loop(cond, body, [0, 0])
```

This is using `tf.while_loop` but it is the same as `tf.cond` for this purposes. If you run this code as is, you will get the same error. If you replace `body` with `body_ok` everything will be fine. The reason is that when the initializer is a function, tensorflow can place it "outside of the control flow context" to make sure it always runs.

To clarify a possible confusion for future readers, the approach to "compute `a` first" is not ideal but for a subtle reason. First, remember that what you are doing here is building a computation graph (assuming you are not using [eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager)). So, you are not actually computing `a`. You are just defining how it **can** be computed. Tensorflow runtime decides what needs to be computed at runtime, depending on the arguments to `session.run()`. So, one might expect that the if the condition is false, the branch returning `a` will not be executed (since it is not needed). Unfortunately, this is not how TensorFlow runtime works. You can find more details in the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063952/confused-by-the-behavior-of-tf-cond), but briefly, TensorFlow runtime will execute all **dependencies** for **either** branch, only the operations inside the `true_fn/false_fn` will be executed conditionally.

Comment: Thanks, this really helps!

Answer (score 6):

The same problem occurs with me while using keras with CNN-LSTM. The code was working fine on GPU server, but when I tried to run it on my local machine, got this weird error.

The following trick works for me.

Solution: clear variables and restart your kernel. This work for me. Maybe someone else getting to exactly the same problem what I am going through will be helpful.

Comment: I was frantically searching for a solution to this error.  I was getting it when applying it on LSTM. Finally, your answer helped me solve it. I am using Google Colab and I stopped getting this error after I restarted my runtime.