# ValueError: Initializer for variable is from inside a control-flow construct, such as a loop or conditional. Use a lambda as the initializer

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

This is the simplified version of an issue I am facing when declaring an LSTM layer inside a control flow in Keras. The line `K.variable(kernel_init([3,3], dtype='float64'), dtype='float64',name='kernel')` is part of the [Keras base_layer.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L279). Hence this line cannot be changed. Based on the reccomendation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51509387/7411022), I tried to create an LSTM network and get the same error. I have boiled it down to the simplified code below.

The following code execution leads to the error

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

def cond(i):
  return i < 3

def body(i):
    kernel_init = lambda x, dtype='float64' : tf.random.normal(x, dtype=dtype)
    vars = K.variable(kernel_init([3,3], dtype='float64'),
                            dtype='float64',
                            name='kernel')
    print("succesfully variable declared")
    return (i+1,vars)

tf.while_loop(cond, body, [0])
```

> ValueError: Initializer for variable while/kernel/ is from inside a control-flow construct, such as a loop or conditional. When creating a variable inside a loop or conditional, use a lambda as the initializer.

Tagging multi-threading since the above code originally runs inside a parallel thread.

Comment: Why do you want to declare the kernel a lot of times?

Comment: The issue is what it says, you cannot initialize a variable within a `tf.while_loop` as this is a control-flow operation.

Comment: @Daniel, the actual while loop is based on whether an event is set or not and it reloads a trained lstm at some regular interval to retrain it on new data.

Comment: @thushv89, but it also suggests an alternative to do it and is shown for a simple case in the question I linked in the post.

Comment: Can't you just assign a new value instead of creating the variable again? That sounds weird and totally goes against the static graph idea that tensorflow follows.

Comment: Well, this might be true @DanielMöller, but given the current situation is there a way to getover this problem?

Comment: Did you try to assign to the existing vars instead of creating new vars?