# how to loop over a tensor object until a condition met

Tags: python, tensorflow, while-loop

I have a tensor like this:

```
masked_bad_col = [[False  True  True False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False]]
```

I want to loop through this tensor untill all elements get `True`.
So I have another function, which will update this tensor, lets call it `uniqueness`.

```
def uniqueness():

   'blah blah blha'
   return tensor1, updated_masked_bad_col
```

I looked at the documentation and got to know that I can do that using `tf.while_loop`. Although, I could not find any example working on boolean stuff.
This is what I have done so far:

```
tensor1, _ = tf.while_loop(masked_bad_col != True, uniqueness)
```

It is obviously incorrect, but don't know how to use each element of `masked_bad_col` as a condition to continue looping through `uniqueness` function.

**Update 1**
This is the method I am trying to call in the loop:

```
corpus = load_corpus('path_to_corpus/train.corpus')
topics = []
vocab, docs = corpus['vocab'], corpus['docs']
number_of_topics = 0
encoder_model = load_keras_model(
    'path_to_model/encoder_model',
    custom_objects={"KCompetitive": KCompetitive})
weights = encoder_model.get_weights()[0]
for idx in range(encoder_model.output_shape[1]):
    token_idx = np.argsort(weights[:, idx])[::-1][:20]
    topics.append([(revdict(vocab)[x]) for x in token_idx])
    number_of_topics += 1

nparr = np.asarray(topics)
# print nparr.shape

unique, indices, count = np.unique(nparr, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)

tensor1 = (np.sum(count[indices].reshape(nparr.shape), axis=1).reshape(1, nparr.shape[0]) / (
        number_of_topics * 20))

def uniqueness_score():
    corpus = load_corpus('path_to_corpus/train.corpus')
    topics = []
    vocab, docs = corpus['vocab'], corpus['docs']
    number_of_topics = 0
    encoder_model = load_keras_model(
        'path_to_model/encoder_model',
        custom_objects={"KCompetitive": KCompetitive})
    weights = encoder_model.get_weights()[0]
    for idx in range(encoder_model.output_shape[1]):
        token_idx = np.argsort(weights[:, idx])[::-1][:20]
        topics.append([(revdict(vocab)[x]) for x in token_idx])
        number_of_topics += 1

    nparr = np.asarray(topics)

    unique, indices, count = np.unique(nparr, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)

    tensor1 = (np.sum(count[indices].reshape(nparr.shape), axis=1).reshape(1, nparr.shape[0]) / (
            number_of_topics * 20))
    return tensor1
```

And this is the way I called this method in the `while_loop`

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

        tensor2, _ = tf.while_loop(
            # Loop condition (negated goal condition)
            lambda tensor1: ~tf.math.reduce_all(tensor1 > tf.reduce_mean(tensor1)),
            # Loop body
            lambda tensor1: uniqueness_score(),
            # Loop variables
            [tensor1])
        # Returned loop value
        print(tensor2.eval())
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to do. [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) does not work like that, it receives functions as condition and body parameters. Conditions are always boolean, so not sure what you mean by that. And I don't really understand what you mean by "I want to loop through this tensor until all elements get `True`". Can you tell what would be the output you would want to get for the example input you are giving?

Comment: @jdehesa Thank you for following with my question. Actually, in the `uniqueness` method, I will do some changing on the tensor until the tensor element of  `updated_masked_bad_col` got all true (and at the same time I have another tensor `tensor1` I am interested in that). To put it another way, I want to change `tensor1` until the whole elements of `updated_masked_bad_col` got true. Does that make sense?

Comment: There is `tensor1` tensor. I will do something on that and drive `updated_masked_bad_col`. but I want to keep doing changing the `tensor1` until I get `updated_masked_bad_col` with all elements are true.

Comment: Let me share the true story and stop being generic. in `tensor1` I will get top 20 of each column, calculate a function on that, the result of the function is a `number`, if the number is less than the `mean`, the `updated_masked_bad_col` for that column will be `False`. But I will shuffle another top20 of the same column, and apply the same function on that until the result number is more than `mean` so that in that case `updated_masked_bad_col` will be true for that column. I will do the same for the rest of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

I think I get an idea of what you want, more or less, but I'm not sure I see the need for the boolean array. If you want to do some iterative process where you compute or retrieve some values until they meet some condition, you can do that without additional arrays. See for example this loop to sample some random values until all of them meet a condition:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Draw five random numbers until all are > 0.5
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.random.set_random_seed(0)
    # Initial values, here simply initialized to zero
    tensor1 = tf.zeros([5], dtype=tf.float32)
    # Loop
    tensor1 = tf.while_loop(
        # Loop condition (negated goal condition)
        lambda tensor1: ~tf.math.reduce_all(tensor1 > 0.5),
        # Loop body
        lambda tensor1: tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(tensor1), dtype=tensor1.dtype),
        # Loop variables
        [tensor1])
    # Returned loop value
    print(tensor1.eval())
    # [0.7778928  0.9396961  0.572209   0.6187117  0.89615726]
```

See if this helps and leave a comment if you are still not sure how to apply this to your particular case.

---

EDIT: Seeing again your question, your `uniqueness` function computed both `tensor1` and the mask, so maybe a more similar analogous code would be this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def sample_numbers(shape, dtype):
    tensor1 = tf.random.uniform(shape, dtype=dtype)
    mask = tensor1 > 0.5
    return tensor1, mask

# Draw five random numbers until all are > 0.5
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.random.set_random_seed(0)
    # Initial values, here simply initialized to zero
    tensor1 = tf.zeros([5], dtype=tf.float32)
    mask = tf.zeros(tf.shape(tensor1), dtype=tf.bool)
    # Loop
    tensor1, _ = tf.while_loop(
        # Loop condition (negated goal condition)
        lambda tensor1, mask: ~tf.math.reduce_all(mask),
        # Loop body
        lambda tensor1, mask: sample_numbers(tf.shape(tensor1), tensor1.dtype),
        # Loop variables
        [tensor1, mask])
    # Returned loop value
    print(tensor1.eval())
    # [0.95553064 0.5170193  0.69573617 0.9501506  0.99776053]
```

Comment: Thank you so much again. In `# Loop body` you call `tf.random.uniform`. Here, can I call a function that shuffle another top 20 of `tensor1`? or I need to pase the implementation of that function here?

Comment: I tried this one: ` # Loop body
        lambda tensor1: uniqueness_score(),` and raises error` and this function returns `tensor1`.

Comment: @sariii That sounds like it should work... I have added another example doing the same but using an external function, trying to get closer to what (I think) you had. Have a look at that, if you are still getting errors maybe you can edit your question with them.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for taking the time and providing the second example which is very close to my case. I had asked a question but then I felt I am not understanding `tf.while_loop` well. so I tried to play with that with a very basic and simple example. I am now have better understanding of that. though still not able to get my code run. I am updating the question with the exact scenario that I have and greatly appreciate it if you can have a look and let me know which part I am missing.

Comment: You might wonder why I have repeated the body of the method right above the method. the reason is that My `tensor1` first time will be initialized through that calculation, I could not get better way to do that. I realy appreciate it if you can help me with this.

Comment: Actually, following the error and this link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515034/keras-tensorflow-initializer-for-variable-is-from-inside-a-control-flow-con`. I decided to use tf2 (which does not need the early execution ...) and it got fixed. Though I need to get this work on tf1. I was wondering if you can help me to fix this so it can be run in tf1 as well? (Apparently I need to define the variable in the loop). Any thought on this is appreciated.

Comment: @sariii I've seen your update, and it seems doable with eager mode but, as it is, quite some work to get it as graph mode. You are trying to load a Keras model multiple times, which is probably not reasonable (you should only need to load it once and use it multiple times), you are using NumPy operations and Python lists instead of TensorFlow operations and tensors, and in any case I don't fully understand what the code does, to be honest. In general, you would need to rewrite all your logic to use TensorFlow operations (without using `tf.Variable`, which is a common mistake).

Comment: I see. as tf14 has no problem switching between NumPy and tensor array I did not change it. But I understand your point. I try to have it in better shape then will ask for help :)

Comment: I had moving out this week and worked on this very little. I could transfer the code to use only tensorflow operation (just in one case I could not). Though, I am not satisfied with the the way I am solving my problem. I was wondering is that okay if I move this comments to chat and there I explain step by step what I am trying to do, then you provide me your valuable insight? I understand that its not good practice to do so but I got stuck at this point (there is only 4 step and I try my best to explain it very clearly). Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I opened a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208905).