# ValueError When creating a variable inside a loop or conditional, use a lambda as the initializer

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to train a UNet for image segmentation and I have the following as part of my network.

```
def inception_block(inputs, depth, splitted=True, activation='relu'):
    actv = LeakyReLU

    c1_1 = Conv2D(int(depth/4), (1, 1), padding='same')(inputs)
    c2_1 = Conv2D(int(depth/8*3), (1, 1),padding='same')(inputs)
    c2_1 = actv()(c2_1)

    if splitted:
        c2_2 = Conv2D(int(depth/2), (1, 3), padding='same')(c2_1)
        c2_2 = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(c2_2)
        c2_2 = actv()(c2_2)
        c2_3 = Conv2D(int(depth/2), (3, 1),padding='same')(c2_2)
    else:
        c2_3 = Conv2D(int(depth/2), (3, 3),  padding='same')(c2_1)

    c3_1 = Conv2D(int(depth/16), (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(inputs)
    c3_1 = actv()(c3_1)

    if splitted:
        c3_2 = Conv2D(int(depth/8), (1, 5), padding='same')(c3_1)
        c3_2 = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(c3_2)
        c3_2 = actv()(c3_2)
        c3_3 = Conv2D(int(depth/8), (5, 1), padding='same')(c3_2)
    else:
        c3_3 = Conv2D(int(depth/8), (5, 5), padding='same')(c3_1)

    p4_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1),padding='same')(inputs)
    c4_2 = Conv2D(int(depth/8), (1, 1), padding='same')(p4_1)

    res = concatenate([c1_1, c2_3, c3_3, c4_2],axis=1)
    res = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(res)
    res=actv()(res)
    return res
```

and

```
  def N2(inputs,Z):
    splitted=True
    act='relu'

    strides=(2,2)
    padding='valid'

    conv1 = (inception_block(inputs, 32, splitted= splitted, activation= act))
    pool1 = poolConvolution2D(32, filters=(3, 3), strides=(2,2))(conv1)
    pool1=Dropout(Z.drop)(pool1)

    conv2 = inception_block(pool1, 64, splitted= splitted, activation=act)
    pool2 = poolConvolution2D(64, filters=(3, 3), strides=(2,2))(conv2)
    pool2=Dropout(Z.drop)(pool2)

    conv3 = inception_block(pool2, 128, splitted=splitted, activation=act)
    pool3 = poolConvolution2D(128, filters=(3, 3), strides=(2,2))(conv3)
    pool3=Dropout(Z.drop)(pool3)
...


def poolConvolution2D(nb_filter, filters, strides=(1, 1)):
    def f(_input):
        conv = Conv2D(nb_filter, filters, strides=strides, padding='same')(_input)

        norm = BatchNormalization(axis=1)(conv)
        return ELU()(norm)
    return f
```

when running the code, I get a `ValueError: Initializer for variable conv2d/kernel/ is from inside a control-flow construct, such as a loop or conditional. When creating a variable inside a loop or conditional, use a lambda as the initializer.`

No, I have browsed posts on Github and on [SO saying this sometimes is caused by concatenating float32 / float64 types with int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393356/how-to-use-tensorflows-dataset-api-iterator-as-an-input-of-a-recurrent-neural/47409487), however this doesn't seem to be the case here. My inputs are of the form `Tensor("main_input", shape=(?, 7, 96, 96), dtype=float32)`.

I am fairly new to using TF and any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: what is `poolConvolution2D`?

Comment: @DanielMöller updated to include poolConvolution2D